# Retrieve datas from database as verital

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my database table .I want to retrieve the horizontal key value to vertical.

```
    city_id  cat_id  value
     100      1       1000
     100      2       2000
     101      1        350
     101      2        500
     102      1       1000
     102      2       2000
     103      1         10
     104      2          5
```

Output:

```
city_id  catagory1    catagory2
100        1000          2000
101         350           500
102        1000          2000
103          10             0
104           0             5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pivot result:

```
select
  city_id, 
  max(case cat_id when 1 then value else 0 end) as category_1,
  max(case cat_id when 2 then value else 0 end) as category_2
from
  my_table
group by
  city_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I should tell you to use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

You will have only one column for all your categories. You just have to split them then.

```
SELECT city_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') as categories
FROM your_table
GROUP BY city_id
```

Here is a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/326a5/3).

Comment: `GROUP BY city_id` does it ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce8a1/3 ... now who gets the score? right ...

Comment: Right, I have done myself at the moment ! ;) You get the score ! :)

Comment: The Fiddle output was not as expected by OP.

Comment: @kmas I never get the score ... but I need 3.000 really urgent! ;)